Hydration failed: Problem with NextJS (v15) and ChakraUI when using components
I am using NextJS 15 and Chakra UI to start creating a simple form, however I am getting errors in console:
However the contents of the path can be displayed, but I don't understand what the problem is as I am new to Next. I followed the ChakraUI installation step by step.
The code I am using is this:
 import { Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function RegisterPage() {
  
  return (
    <Box>
      
      <h1>Register</h1>
    </Box>
   
  );
}


you need to add suppressHydrationWarning just like in the chakra docs in the step 3:
import { Provider } from "@/components/ui/provider"

export default function RootLayout(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const { children } = props
  return (
    <html suppressHydrationWarning> {/* add this property */}
      <body>
        <Provider>{children}</Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}


I forgot to mention that I already added that property in the root layout and I still get the same error.

are you sure? that property suppresses hydration warnings. i tried to it on next@15 and i got hydration warnings as expected when i omit it. thats interesting if you still got hydration warnings

To solve this I had to modify @/components/ui/provider in the following way:
'use client';

import { Provider as ChakraProvider } from "@/components/ui/provider";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function Provider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const [hydrated, setHydrated] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
         // this forces a rerender
        setHydrated(true)
    }, [])

    if (!hydrated) {
        // this returns null on first render, so the client and server match
        return null
    } 

    return <ChakraProvider>{children}</ChakraProvider>;
}


The Chakra documentation for Next.js explicitly mentions adding suppressHydrationWarning to the html tag in RootLayout. This solved the issue for me.
Chakra UI documentation here.


import { Provider } from "@/components/ui/provider"

export default function RootLayout(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const { children } = props
  return (
    <html suppressHydrationWarning>
      <body>
        <Provider>{children}</Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}



